# Select a specific text form .TXT and group the content

Tags: php, regex, r

I want to select a specific text for a datavisualisation.
My plan is to select text form a textfile

```
 file.txt
```

This file looks like this

```
 Switzerland (SUI) # - 23 players
 (1) GK Pascal ZuberbÃ¼hler ## 40, Basel (SUI)
 (12) GK Diego Benaglio ## 1, Nacional (POR)
 (21) GK Fabio Coltorti ## 2, Grasshoppe (SUI)
 (3) DF Ludovic Magnin ## 30, Stuttgart (GER)
```

I want to select the

```
(SUI), (POR), (SUI) & (GER)
```

So I made a Regex

```
#\W([A-Z]){3}\S#
```

This is the code I already made

```
$myfile = fopen("2006/ch-switzerland.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo fread($myfile,filesize("2006/ch-switzerland.txt"));
    fclose($myfile);
```

So now I want to select the specific text and put it in groups so that I will see

```
(SUI)2, (POR), (GER)
```

My PHP skills are not really great so I hope you could be able to help me.

Thank you for your time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `file_get_contents`, there's an easier way to read a file. However, as you seem to want to skip the first line (naming the soccer team), I'd prefer reading the file as lines. This can be done with `file`.

Also, you do not need the round brackets around your regular expression letters: `#\W[A-Z]{3}\S#`

```
<?php

# We use an array for counting
$counts = array();

# Read the file lines into an array
$lines = file('test.txt');

# Iterate over all lines but the first (1 means we start at line 1, instead of 0)
foreach (array_slice($lines, 1) as $line) {
    # Do the regular expression and check if it was a match
    $was_match = preg_match('#\W[A-Z]{3}\S#', $line, $match);
    if ($was_match)
    {
        # check if we already counted this country
        if (!isset($counts[$match[0]]))
            $counts[$match[0]] = 0; # if not, set count to initial zero

        # increment the country count by one
        $counts[$match[0]] += 1;
    }
}

var_dump($counts);

// array(3) {
//   ["(SUI)"]=>
//   int(2)
//   ["(POR)"]=>
//   int(1)
//   ["(GER)"]=>
//   int(1)
// }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked for me! Thank you for your afford.
(small detail you forgot the backets after the <pre> if (!isset($counts[$match[0]]))</pre>

Comment: You mean the curly ones `{}`? In most languages with C-style-syntax (also in PHP) one does not need the braces, if **only one** statement follows.